# How to display default plot in www/ before actionButton is clicked R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, action-button

Here is a sample code to generate a plot upon clicking the actionButton.

```
shinyApp(
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    inputPanel( 
        numericInput("n", "n", 10),
        actionButton("update", "Update")
    ),
    plotOutput("plot")
)),

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    values <- reactiveValues()
    values$data <- c()

    obs <- observe({
        input$update
        isolate({ values$data <- c(values$data, runif(as.numeric(input$n), -10, 10)) })
    }, suspended=TRUE)

    obs2 <- observe({
        if (input$update > 0) obs$resume()
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        dat <- values$data
        hist(dat)
    })
})
```

)

I would like to display a default plot which is in www/test.png to appear when the application is launched. And then change the plot after clicking the actionButton as per the user input.

Comment: is it necessary to show a png or would be a default R-plot sufficient as well? Both is possible yet the later is easier

Comment: It needs to be a png or whatever image format but which is already generated and stored in www/ directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I create a simple plot, export it as an image (manually, not in code) and name it `Rplot.png` (save it where you want):

```
plot(mtcars$mpg)
```

Then, in the shiny app, we have to distinguish two situations :

- when the app starts, no button is clicked yet, we render the image with `renderImage`
- when we click on the button, we replace `renderImage` with `renderPlot` and render an interactive plot

This means that we must use `uiOutput` in `ui` part so that we can choose the output to be an image or a plot according to the situation.

Here's an example (I didn't adapt your code but it should not be too difficult):

```
library(shiny)

# determine your path to image here (you should use the package "here" to do so)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("choice", "Choose", choices = names(mtcars)),
  actionButton("run", "Run"),
  uiOutput("some_ui")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ### "Static" part: no click on actionButton yet
  output$some_ui <- renderUI({
    imageOutput("image_plot")
  })

  output$image_plot <- renderImage({
    list(src = "Rplot.png",
         contentType = 'image/png')
  }, deleteFile = FALSE) # Do not forget this option



  ### Click on actionButton
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    output$some_ui <- renderUI({
      plotOutput("dynamic_plot")
    })

    output$dynamic_plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(mtcars[[input$choice]])
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Both answers work in this case. But don't know how to accept both.

Comment: any clue with the new thread. Seems like im missing simple basics over there.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use renderUI, so you can either show an image or a R plot. This should do what you desire:

```
shinyApp(
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    inputPanel( 
      numericInput("n", "n", 10),
      actionButton("update", "Update")
    ),
    uiOutput("out")
  )),

  shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {
    values <- reactiveValues()

    # check if plot has been already rendered
    check <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
    values$data <- c()

    observeEvent(input$update, {
      # set check to TRUE
      check(TRUE)
      input$update
      values$data <- c(values$data, runif(as.numeric(input$n), -10, 10))
      dat <- values$data
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        hist(dat)
      })
    })

    # initial picture. 
    output$picture <- renderImage({
      list(src = "temp.png")
    }, deleteFile = FALSE)


    output$out <- renderUI({
      # in the  beginning, check is FALSE and the picture is shown
      if (!check()) {
        imageOutput("picture")
      } else {
        # as soon as the button has been pressed the first time,
        # the plot is shown
        plotOutput("plot")
      }


    })
  }) 

)
```

Comment: where should the "temp.png" be located in this case?

Comment: in the same folder as your app.R file is.

Comment: `##render initial picture. heatmap_rna is the id for the uiOutput() in ui.R##
output$heatmap_rna <-  renderImage({
     list(src = "/www/heatmap.png")
   }, deleteFile = FALSE)

###generate plot upon action button##
output$heatmap_rna <- renderPlot({
  if(input$action==0) return()
     print("heatmap_rna_renderPlot")
     heatmap_render()  ##custom function which produces the heatmap
     })`

Comment: i have adapted the code given by you in the above way to my need. `renderPlot` is generated by a custom function `heatmap_render()`.  And instead of `observeEvent` i have used `input$action ==0`. Is there something wrong in this as the above code gives the error `Error in pngfun: invalid quartz() device size`

Comment: no clue of how to help here. In case you cannot fix it, please open another question on SO

Comment: i have new OP related to this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811581/how-to-render-default-plot-in-r-shiny` if you have time to check.

Comment: how is this different from my answer below?

Comment: it is not different but as i have explained both approaches are not working in my case. it may be different with the way the action Button trigger is written.

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this has been solved a while, but I needed a solution, without uiOutput. Plus I find this much simpler.

```
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      actionButton("btn", "Click me"),
      br(),
      plotOutput('some_plot', width = '100%')
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$some_plot <- renderPlot({
        if (!input$btn) {
          # default plot
          plot(1, 1, col = 'red')
        } else{
          # updated plot
          plot(1000, 1000, col = 'green')
        }
      })
    }
  )
}
```